# Attempt to invote virtual method on a null object with getResources in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm using `getResources()` for getting the string values in the `strings.xml` file. I created a variable in my class similar like this:

```
public class Example extends Activity {
   String okhttp_tp = getResources().getString(R.string.okhttp_tp);
   // The rest of my script.
}
```

And when I want to use it with the OKhttp request like this `.addHeader("X-Client-Type", okhttp_tp)` it gives me this error directly when I want to launch my app:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
```

I have tried the following rules:

```
1. String okhttp_tp = getResources().getString(R.string.okhttp_tp);
2. String okhttp_tp = (String) getResources().getString(R.string.okhttp_tp);
3. String okhttp_tp = getResources().getString(R.string.okhttp_tp).toString();
4. String okhttp_tp = (String) getResources().getString(R.string.okhttp_tp).toString();
5. String okhttp_tp = Example.this.getResources().getString(R.string.okhttp_tp);
```

I also tried to do this:

```
String doPostRequest(String url, String json[]) throws IOException {
   Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .addHeader("X-Client-Type", getResources().getString(R.string.okhttp_tp).toString())
      .url(okhttp_login_url)
      .url(url)
      .post(body)
      .build();
}
```

But none of these work and the app crashes after launching. Do I miss something? Something I forgot?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: make sure calling `getResources ` inside any method instead of at class level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a better and efficient way to do that.
Instead of saving it in strings.xml and retrieving ,you can create a static global constant variable.

**AppConstants.java**

```
class AppConstants{
 public static final String ok_http = "value here";
}
```

**Usage**

```
String doPostRequest(String url, String json[]) throws IOException {
   Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .addHeader("X-Client-Type",AppConstants.ok_http)
      .url(okhttp_login_url)
      .url(url)
      .post(body)
      .build();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. (Note that you have a syntax error it must be `@Override`

Comment: I tried your solution, but now I want to access the variable outside the `onCreate()` function, can you tell me how I can do that?

Comment: Thanks! But it returned `null` for me instead of the value

Comment: you need to use that variable after its initialization

Comment: I did, but it still returned null for me.

Comment: this will help i guess

Answer (score 0):

You can access resources only in `onCreate()` or later in the activity life cycle. Instance initialization phase is too early.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.